# How to migrate an anciant form saved with new version in ORBEON?

Tags: xhtml, field, orbeon, savechanges

How to keep an anciant form saved with new version.
I used the CRUD API and i followed steps using two methods:

1. Retrieve the XML of a form by imposing the most recent version number:

   - Create a form with an earlier version : test with `docId=fd4f49aad1ac3eb5a8ac29b0fa15a8cc1ec6ee6e` and  `version=1`
   - Run this command: `curl -v -k -H
     "Orbeon-Form-Definition-Version: 2"  http://127.0.0.1:8080/orbeon/fr/service/persistence/crud/newProject/test/data/fd4f49aad1ac3eb5a8ac29b0fa15a8cc1ec6ee6e/data.xml`
   - This results in a "400 bad request". If I put the old version 1 instead of 2, there is no error.
2. Create an empty test form with the latest version and fill it with
   the form created with the old version

   - Run this command `curl -v -k -H
     "Orbeon-Form-Definition-Version: 1"
     http://127.0.0.1:8080/orbeon/fr/service/persistence/crud/newProject/test/data/fd4f49aad1ac3eb5a8ac29b0fa15a8cc1ec6ee6e/data.xml >>myData`. ⇒ the XML file save to a directory.
   - Save an empty test form with the new version (`documentId =
     40239f94e49538db4e94e4f60ad7b4f312c23f3e`)
   - Run this command `curl -v -k -d @mydata.xml -H
     "Content-Type: application/xml" -H "Orbeon-Form-Definition-Version:
     2" -X PUT  http://127.0.0.1:8080/orbeon/fr/service/persistence/crud/newProject/test/data/40239f94e49538db4e94e4f60ad7b4f312c23f3e/data.xml` ⇒ results 500 Internal server error.

This is a stacktrace when the error was occured:

```
> |An Error has Occurred                                                                                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Fatal error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.                               |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Application Call Stack                                                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|oxf:/ops/pfc/xforms-xml-submission.xpl                                            |reading processor output      | 111|
|Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·|
|element=<p:output name="data" ref="instance"/>                                                                        |
|name   =data                                                                                                          |
|ref    =instance                                                                                                      |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|oxf:/ops/pfc/xforms-xml-submission.xpl                                            |reading processor output      | 102|
|Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·Â·|
|element=<p:output name="data" id="raw-instance"/>                                                                     |
|name   =data                                                                                                          |
|id     =raw-instance                                                                                                  |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|:/Users/fkammoun/AppData/Local/Temp/upload__5a2c8fe_15fbb88e967__8000_00000000.tmp|                              |   1|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: org.orbeon.oxf.common.ValidationException                                                                  |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xml.XMLParsing$ErrorHandler         |fatalError                    |XMLParsing.java               | 221|
|orbeon.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper      |fatalError                    |                              |    |
|orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter         |reportError                   |                              |    |
|orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter         |reportError                   |                              |    |
|orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter         |reportError                   |                              |    |
|orbeon.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner               |reportFatalError              |                              |    |
|.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$TrailingMiscDispatcher|dispatch                      |                              |    |
|n.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl|scanDocument                  |                              |    |
|orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration    |parse                         |                              |    |
|orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration    |parse                         |                              |    |
|orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser             |parse                         |                              |    |
|orbeon.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser     |parse                         |                              |    |
|processor.generator.URLGenerator$URLResourceHandler|readXML                       |URLGenerator.java             |1042|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.URLGenerator$1  |readImpl                      |URLGenerator.java             | 545|
|essor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter|read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 257|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl  |read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 394|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsSAX                |ProcessorImpl.java            | 262|
|ssor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor$InternalTopOutput$1|run                           |PipelineProcessor.java        | 535|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|executeParents                |PipelineProcessor.java        | 696|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|access$400                    |PipelineProcessor.java        |  60|
|cessor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor$InternalTopOutput|readImpl                      |PipelineProcessor.java        | 531|
|essor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter|read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 257|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl  |read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 394|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsSAX                |ProcessorImpl.java            | 262|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsSAX                |ProcessorImpl.java            | 266|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.IdentityProcessor$1       |readImpl                      |IdentityProcessor.java        |  33|
|essor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter|read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 257|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl  |read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 394|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsSAX                |ProcessorImpl.java            | 262|
|orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor$1$1|run                           |PipelineProcessor.java        |  93|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|executeChildren               |PipelineProcessor.java        | 679|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|access$000                    |PipelineProcessor.java        |  60|
|g.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor$1|readImpl                      |PipelineProcessor.java        |  91|
|essor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter|read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 257|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl  |read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 394|
|processor.pipeline.choose.ConcreteChooseProcessor$1|readImpl                      |ConcreteChooseProcessor.java  | 126|
|essor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter|read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 257|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl  |read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 394|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsSAX                |ProcessorImpl.java            | 262|
|orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor$1$1|run                           |PipelineProcessor.java        |  93|
```

Answer (score 0):

The following explains the errors you got in the 2 cases you mentioned:

1. When retrieving a document, you can't specify a form version. That information is attached to the document, identified by document id, and that version number is returned to you by the API when you're doing a `GET`.
2. The form definition version for a given document id isn't expected to change. This explains the error you're getting the second case, as you're trying to update a document, and provide a new form definition version, which isn't allowed. In fact, when you're updating a document, you're not expected to provide any form definition version, as that information can't change and is already stored in the database.

And to answer the question in the title, if you have a document created with version 1 of the form and you want to store a version of that document after you upgrade it to correspond to version 2 of the form, then you need to store it using a different document id.

Comment: thanks @avernet for your response, but i thought of doing this solution as indicated in the 2 nd point. Is there another way to do it?